# Change the title of previously published page in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I had to change the page title for few pages which were first published 1-2 weeks ago. But google analytics is still showing the old page title.

Is there any way to force google analytic to store the new page title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot change historical data (with the possible exception of transaction data).